# Помогите с написанием парсера txt файла

Tags: парсер

> Уточненный вопрос задан здесь: [Как выдернуть из строки нужный кусок, указав начало и конец области поиска](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444907/181472)

Добрый день. Мне необходимо написать парсер txt файла. Есть небольшие навыки программирования на java под андроид и совсем небольшие на python.

Если говорить конкретнее, есть файл, содержащий в себе вот такие строки:

**96.246.236.151:3389;greenlightexp\admin;P@ssw0rd (greentech;Bazzz628) | Country: United States | State: New York | City: Long Island City | ZIP: 11101 | ISP: Verizon FiOS |**

есть строка такого формата, 
надо оставлять только **IP:PORT:login;pass**

```
(96.246.236.151:3389;greenlightexp\admin;P@ssw0rd)
```

подскажите на чем это было бы проще написать, желательно при этом не тащить на машину, на которой запустится скрипт сторонние либы и прочее

Comment: Может https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed?

Comment: На чем писать - это полностью ваш выбор. Для тех, кто пишет под java - будет проще написать на java, тем, кто пишет под питон, будет удобнее писать на питоне.

А использовать вам стоит регулярные выражения, которые есть в перечисленных языках

Comment: Для решения данной задачи подойдет и простой `grep`: если после пароля всегда есть пробел, а ник/пароль пробел не содержат, то должно отработать следующее: `grep -oP '^[^\s]+' infile > outfile`. Если же ник/пароль могут содержать пробелы, тогда необходимо указать каким образом можно однозначно выделить требуемый текст. Например, сейчас (если пробелы могут быть в пароле) не понятно почему пароль - это `P@ssw0rd`, а не `P@ssw0rd (greentech` (исхожу из того, что точка с запятой служит разделителем данных)

Comment: Или это "вопрос-опросник", или "работа за автора". И так и так достоин закрытия и/или переписывания.

Comment: Не нужны ему регулярные выражения. Ему хватит split по `;` , взятие первых трех элементов и split первого элемента по `:` Для небольших навыков для Java и совсем небольших для Python регулярные выражения станут ступором.

Comment: @ReinRaus, сплит по `;` не поможет получить пароль, и регулярки с языком как бы не связаны - сомневаюсь, что админы знают достаточно какой-либо язык, но тем же grep'ом или sed'ом пользоваться они умеют. А если язык не важен, тогда вообще зачем заморачиваться, если можно и без него это сделать? И да, с `\s` в отрицании поторопился, пытался простое решение показать, надо было хотя бы так: `grep -oP '^[^ ]+' infile > outfile`

Comment: Я не жду готового ответа, это не вопрос-опросник. На стаке я недавно. Я задавал уже более конкретные вопросы по яве с примером своего кода. Сейчас передо мной стоит задача, с которой я никогда не сталкивался. Я пиал DOM-парсеры на питоне. Поэтому единственное, что мне пришло в голову это задать вопрос в стиле "с чего начать, на чем писать". Человек, который попросил меня написать такой парсер, хотел чтобы в систему не нужно было ставить SDK и сторонние либы. Поскольку я более менее знаком с синтаксисом питона, готов переформулировать свой вопрос. Есть ведь py2exe. Может быть есть и либа какая?

Comment: закрывайте, создам новую тему, где перефразирую, тем более я определился с языком и либой