# Как выдернуть из строки нужный кусок, указав начало и конец области поиска

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день, у меня есть файл со строками такого вида:

```
96.246.236.151:3389;greenlightexp\admin;P@ssw0rd (greentech;Bazzz628) | Country: United States | State: New York | City: Long Island City | ZIP: 11101 | ISP: Verizon FiOS |
```

Мне нужно распарсить строку на отдельные составляющие: IP,PORT,login,pass

Я решил использовать библиотеку regex для python 2.7, т.к. с python уже раньше немного работал.

Я сумел найти IP-адрес следующим образом:

```
s = "96.246.236.151:3389;greenlightexp\admin;P@ssw0rd (greentech;Bazzz628) | Country: United States | State: New York | City: Long Island City | ZIP: 11101 | ISP: Verizon FiOS |"
pattern1 = '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'
ip = re.findall(pattern1, s)
```

Теперь хотелось бы найти другие данные - к примеру пароль. Но я не понимаю как задать параметр поиска, чтобы требуемый мне кусок текста шел после определенного символа или группы символов и заканчивался соответственно тоже каким-то условием.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = r"96.246.236.151:3389;greenlightexp\admin;P@ssw0rd (greentech;Bazzz628)    | Country: United States | State: New York | City: Long Island City | ZIP:  11101 | ISP: Verizon FiOS |"
# я понимаю, что логин - admin (т.е нужно пометить, что строка сырая) 
pattern1 = r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{4});.*?\\(.+?);(.+?)\s'
# предположил, что пароль отделен пробелом
ip, port, login, passwd = re.findall(pattern1, s)[0]
```

Чтение файла построчно

```
with open("README.rst","rt") as fo :
   for line in fo.readlines():
       print line
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо ! Работает как часы. Но таких строк в файле много и они все идут в столбик, т.е. разделяются только переходом на новую строку, т.е. после последнего в строке знака "I" идет переход на новую строку и там уже аналогичная строка начинается

Как можно поступить в том случае, если мне нужно все их распарсить подобным образом ? Я полагаю было бы разумно разбить документ на list, содержащий список строк, а затем уже в цикле парсить каждую ?

Comment: построчно читайте файл  <br>

    with open("README.rst","rt") as fo :
        for line in fo.readlines():
             print line

Comment: @sva можно обойтись без readlines(), просто for line in fo: print line.

Comment: Снова проблема. Вот код:

with open("README.rst","rt") as fo :
   for line in fo.readlines():
       print line

проблема в отм, что я изначально одну строку из текстового файла ради "потестить" помещал в переменную s, а теперь я получается построчно работаю с файлом. Не совсем понимаю как теперь распарсить txt файл построчно.

Comment: пробовал так:




with open("IPs.txt","rt") as fo:
   for line in fo.readlines():
       print line(re.findall(pattern1, line))





Пишет TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 2):

Если в паттерне задать какую-то подстроку в скобках, то findall будет выдавать список на единичный результат

```
s = "96.246.236.151:3389;greenlightexp\admin;P@ssw0rd (greentech;Bazzz628) | Country: United States | State: New York | City: Long Island City | ZIP: 11101 | ISP: Verizon FiOS |"
pattern = re.compile("(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):\d*;(.*?);(.*?)\s", re.DOTALL)
results = pattern.findall(s)
results # output: [('96.246.236.151', 'greenlightexp\x07dmin', 'P@ssw0rd')]
```