# Python Построчное чтение файла с выборкой по регулярным выражениям в цикле

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Добрый день. Есть txt файл со строками следующего вида:

```
96.246.236.151:3389;greenlightexp\admin;P@ssw0rd (greentech;Bazzz628)    | Country: United States | State: New York | City: Long Island City | ZIP:  11101 | ISP: Verizon FiOS |
```

Таких строк там много, мне необходимо разобрать строку на составляющие: IP, Port, Username, Password

Пользуюсь либой regex на питоне 2.7 и задаю вот такой паттерн

```
pattern1 = r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{4});.*?\\(.+?);(.+?)\s'
ip, port, login, passwd = re.findall(pattern1, s)
```

Но я не могу понять как мне делать это в цикле:

```
with open("IPs.txt","rt") as fo:
    for line in fo.readlines():
        print line
```

Вообще задача в том, чтобы пройтись по файлу, получить из него нужные данные и в том же виде столбиком запринтить это все в другой txt файл в уже требуемом виде. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Я думаю тебе поможет использование груп. Почитай для своего языка, я не знаю как будет в питоне, но суть такая - ты разбиваешь регексп на группы( в твоем случае будет групы для IP, Port etc) и далее ты просто берешь нужную группу и делаешь с ней что захочешь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, в чём отличие от [прошлого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444907/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0), то ответ может выглядеть так:

```
import re

pattern = r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{4});.*?\\(.+?);(.+?)\s'
regexpr = re.compile(pattern)
with open('IPs.txt') as in_file:
    with open('result.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            try:
                ip, port, login, passwd = regexpr.match(line).groups()
            except AttributeError:
                print('Error: ' + line)
            out_file.write('ip={}, port={}, login={}, passwd={}\n'.format(
                ip, port, login, passwd))
```

**UPD:**

Исправил опечатку. Проблема была в том, что метод `finditer` возвращает генератор результатов проверки регулярного выражения. Выражение

```
ip, port, login, passwd = regexpr.finditer(line)
```

пытается получить четыре совпадения всего паттерна в строке, когда такое совпадение только одно. В итоге и возникает указанная вами ошибка.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Funk/Desktop/parser2.py", line 8, in <module>
    ip, port, login, passwd = regexpr.finditer(line)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Comment: как я понимаю он ругается на то, что в конструкторе должны присутствовать 2 аргумента (pattern и через запятую уже переменная, в нашем случае line), я попробовал так сделать и у меня появилась ошибка:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Funk/Desktop/parser2.py", line 8, in <module>
    ip, port, login, passwd = regexpr.finditer(pattern, line)
TypeError: an integer is required`

Comment: Нет, я использовал скомпилированное выражение, ему нужна только сама строка. Все ли строки в файле имеют одинаковый формат?

Comment: да, все строки одинаковые, могу даже скинуть файл ) только не знаю как его прикрепить

Comment: А последняя пустая строка, например?

Comment: нет, проверил, нет пустой строки в конце

Comment: @Madcap, определи, какая строка не подходит под выражение и покажи её.

Comment: @Madcap Нашёл ошибку в своём решении. Прощу прощения.

Comment: мне немного неловко, я ведь тоже не заметил/не догадался ) огромное вам спасибо за помощь, очень выручили !